# Angular2 - How to reference an image in the template

Tags: angular, dart

I have this structure:

[image]

And I want to reference "logo.svg" in my component.
Like this:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<img src="logo.svg">')
class AppComponent {}
```

What should I put in the `src` attribute to reference the logo correctly? Is there a specific scheme to use?

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: I think it should be `[src]="../lib/logo.svg"`;

Comment: Why with brackets @micronyks? I'd put the static assets into a subfolder in the `web` directory, so it's clear that they can be accessed through `assets/logo.svg` for instance.

Comment: @rinukkusu, thats angular2 way binding. I'm not sure thats why I wrote `I think`. I believed he needs to go 2 levels up (into lib) and then `logo.svg`.

Comment: With Dart everything gets compiled into a build folder, with all the `.dart` files being merged into one Javascript file and the static assets being on the same level with the same folder structure they have in `web` for instance. So going into that `lib` folder doesn't seem like a good idea. Also: I wouldn't bind a string like that in a Angular 2 template.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My background is not dart at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular 5.0.0 you can reference it like this:

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<img src="packages/angular_app/logo.svg">')
class AppComponent {}
```

Replace `angular_app` with the *name* defined in your *pubspec.yaml*.